# Python GC: What's the meaning: Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular float

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

When I read the doc of [gc.collect()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect). There is a saying: **Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular float.**

I'm quite confused. What's the meaning of this saying?

```py
import gc
l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
l = None
gc.collect()
```

Does it mean that even though the `list [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` has no reference after `l = None`, the list's elements `1.0, 2.0, 3.0` cannot be garbage collected since it is `float`. However, if it's `int` [1, 2, 3], then elements will be freed. Why? It's quite counterintuitive. Could we give me a solid example, what's the meaning of `Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular float.`

PS:
Does it mean that if I have a function which will generate list of float in intermediate step but not return it out. Since float cannot be gc, if I repeatedly call this function, it has risk of memory leak?

```
import random


def f():
    l = [random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(100_000_000)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 1
    while True:
        print(f"{count=}")
        count += 1
        f()
```

Comment: Given that the documentation mentions a "particular implementation", it would help to mention which particular implementation you are using (e.g., python 3.8.10 on Linux or whatever you are actually using)   Also, given that you went to the trouble to create that program with the while loop, did you actually try it and check whether it ran out of memory?  I would be rather surprised if it did.

Comment: my point here is that if, for example, you were using a very recent version of python3 on Linux it would likely be possible to give an answer that would be accurate for that version.   The short answer, at least with respect to that platform, is that the documentation you read does not at all imply that float objects will be leaked, but a longer answer would have to provide some information about the nature of garbage collection and how this relates, or not, to float objects.